# Can you post a Linkedin recommendation using the Linkedin API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

To improve recommendations and to help Linkedin, I need api access for posting recommendations. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs to post recommendations, only the [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#recommendations) to pull recommendations.

Comment: Are there any updates on the feature of Posting recommendation to linkedin via APIs.Are there any workaround to add something to the User Profile on the lines of recommendation.

Comment: Its 2021, is it still the same??